# WPF DataGrid in textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid in XAML and C # and I want to select a row and   display the row in the text box, it is not a DataGridView

```
x:Name="dtGConsultas" ItemsSource= "{Binding }" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,3,0,0" Grid.Row="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Height="111" Width="598" Grid.RowSpan="3" 
SelectionChanged="dtGConsultas_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Comment: what about bind selected item to the text box ?

Comment: I want to select a row that shows the datagrid and that this data that shows the row is seen in the textbox

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in several ways:

1. You can bind `SelectedItem` to some property and then display it
2. You can bind `TextBox` value to the `DataGrid`'s `SelectedItem`
3. You can set the `TextBox` value on each call of `SelectionChanged` method

If You would be using MVVM pattern, You should pick **1st** option.

Other **2nd** an **3rd** options are useful for You, but in bigger (complex) applications this solutions would cause issues to read the code easily & maintain it. **Not recommended.**

---

**Examples:**

1. **MVVM approach**

*ViewModel file:*

```
using using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class MyViewModel
{
    //add implementation of INotifyPropertyChange & propfull
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MySrcList { get; set; }

    //add implementation of INotifyPropertyChange & propfull
    public MyItem SelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

*View:*

```
<UserControl ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:MyProject />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    ...

    <DataGrid
         ItemsSource="{Binding MySrcList}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
```

---

2. **Binding `TB` value to value of `DataGrid`'s `SelectedItem`**

*Xaml file:*

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid
        x:Name="dtGConsultas"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MySrcList}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding dtGConsultas.SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

*Code-behind (C# file):*

```
public class MyUserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public List<MyItem> MySrcList = new List<MyItem>();
}
```

---

3. **Update in method (Code-behind):**

*Xaml file:*

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid
        x:Name="dtGConsultas"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MySrcList}" 
        SelectionChanged="dtGConsultas_SelectionChanged"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="MyTbx"/>
</Grid>
```

*Code-Behind (C# file):*

```
public class MyUserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public List<MyItem> MySrcList = new List<MyItem>();

    private void dtGConsultas_SelectionChanged( /* args */)
    {
        MyTbx.Text = dtGConsultas.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: NOT MVC, it is wpf with C #

Comment: @AlexisRS -> with WPF there is common pattern called `MVVM`. View (XAML file) is there just for formating the "GUI" and all the logic, property definition, methods are hidden in `ViewModel` (C# file). And in that approach You should **minimize** use of `Code-Behind` (direct method calls).

Comment: @AlexisRS - which of them? What is the error message?

Comment: I am working with a project WPF is not ASP.NET nor windows forms without the mvvm model and in wpf datagridview does not exist.

Comment: The message is: DataGridView is not compatible with a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project

Comment: So why have u not used `DataGrid` then? =)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a column that contains a checkbox and you bind it. Then juste check if (Your_List.element.CheckBox==true). you can get a list whit your checked elements

Comment: I believe this answer is not what is OP asking for.